# How do you resize tables in an erd diagram in DBeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

When I click on a given table in an erd diagram in DBeaver I simply cant resize it.  The table names get cut off. What am I missing ?

Comment: Ah. Alright, thank you.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - I thought that dba admin tool questions were on-topic here? I know that I've answered a few pgadmin questions and MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Come back @user189533 - all is forgiven! :-) - and also, welcome to the forum! :-)